# run php sql query through javascript/jquery to hide an entry

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

On my website, I am trying to remove (hide) an sql entry in a table without refreshing the screen.

Currently, each visible entry is displayed in a div with an id of schedule000 where 000 is the id number of the entry. Each has a delete button:

```
<div id="btn_delete" class="schedule-delete" onclick="deleteEvent(schedule'.$row['id'].');"></div>
```

while the function is

```
function deleteEvent(id) {
    var delurl = "..schedule/index.php?d="+String(id.id.substring(8));
    $.get(delurl);
    $(id).hide('slow');
    return false;
}
```

I found that get function after searching the internet but I couldn't seem to get it to work. 
I'm looking for suggestions or a new solution.

Thanks

as a side note:
this is part of the page that it is calling

```
if (isset($_GET['d'])) {
    $id = $_GET['d'];
    $query = "UPDATE schedule SET visible=0 WHERE id='$id'";
    if (!(mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()))) {
        echo 'failed to delete';
    }
```

EDIT: Using Sven's method, I now have:

```
function del_item() {
    try {
        var item_id = $(this).attr('item_id'); 
        var item = $(this).parent().parent(); //parent().paren... until you reach the element that you want to delete 
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "../schedule/index.php",
          data: { id: item_id},
          success: function() {
              //fade away and remove it from the dom
              $(element).fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
          },
          error: function() {
              alert('failed to delete');
          }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

along with the document ready function and

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'd' && isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $query = "UPDATE schedule SET visible=0 WHERE id='$id'";
        if (!(mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()))) {
            echo 'failed to delete';
        }
        die("J! :)");
    }
```

Comment: Using `GET` method for actually deleting data is a bad idea, that is what `POST` is for. Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). (Also: send data to `../schedule/`, not `..schedule/`.)

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my '/' error. I understand why you say don't use get for that, but how could I use POST without the page refreshing? (Within the GET I'm going to add a check for who is trying to use the function. Also, I will look into your PDO suggestion

Comment: You are allowing a user to update your database through the url, make sure they are a valid user with the proper credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

Add the item id to the delete button like this:

```
<div id="btn_delete" class="schedule-delete" item_id="' . $row['id'] . '"></div>
```

​The javascript of that page:

```
function del_item() {
    var item_id = $(this).attr('item_id'); 
    var item = $(this).parent(); //parent().paren... until you reach the element that you want to delete 

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "url_to_your_remove_script.php",
      data: { id: item_id},
      success: function() {
          //fade away and remove it from the dom
          $(item).fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
      },
      error: your_error_func
    });
}

​$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.schedule-delete').click(del_item);
});​
```

And for the php delete page (`url_to_your_remove_script.php`):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
        //your update query here

        die("J! :)");
    }

    //no id, return error
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error :(');
?>
```

You can find more information about $.ajax here: [click](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Hope this helps.

PS: Didn't tested the code, but it should work.

Comment: After some editing of your code, I got it to work. Thanks! I wish I could up you..but I don't have 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the id to delete as a string. The query becomes "WHERE id='001', but that should be "WHERE id=1". So, parse the id in your javascript as an integer with 'parseInt' before adding it to the delurl variable.

```
    var id = parseInt(id.id.substring(8));
var delurl = "../schedule/index.php?d="+id;
...etc
```

remove the '' from the query

Comment: perhaps he has set his id as a string in his database. Would not be the smartest thing, but no way to know...